# Create a rds instance using python: having status always = creating

Tags: python, amazon-rds

Im trying to create a rds instance using python.

I have this code below to create an instance and then I want to show my print "Instance is now running" when the instance have status available.

The problem is that, when appears the  available status in aws managment console, in my console application still appears always  status = creating and the code dont get out of while loop:

The result Im having:

```
    ....
    creating
    233
    creating
    234
    ...
```

The code:

```
instance = conn.create_dbinstance(...)

print "Waiting for instance to be up and running"

status = instance.status
inc = 0
while status != 'available':
    sleep(5)
    status = instance.status
    print status
    inc=inc +1
    print inc

if status == 'available':
    print "Instance is now running"
```

Do you see why this can be happening?

Comment: Where is the variable `db` coming from, and why are you checking `db.status` instead of `instance.status`?

Comment: Sorry , I put the wrong code , I updated now correctly!

Comment: The boto docs aren't always clear about when results such as `DBInstance.status` are fetched on-demand via the API vs. being returned from an earlier, cached lookup. I'm betting that here, the `instance.status` call you are returning is just returning the same (cached) result each time. Try `status = conn.get_all_dbinstances(instance_id=instance.id)[0].status` instead of `status = instance.status` inside your while loop.

Comment: Thank you, your solution using the instance_id parameter worked perfectly! Can you give the answer to I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boto [docs](https://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/rds.html#module-boto.rds.dbinstance) aren't always clear about when results such as DBInstance.status are fetched on-demand via the API vs. being returned from an earlier, cached lookup. I'm betting that here, the instance.status call you are using is just returning the same (cached) result each time.

Try

```
status = conn.get_all_dbinstances(instance_id=instance.id)[0].status
```

instead of

```
status = instance.status
```

inside your while loop.

Answer (score 1):

Python program to print all RDS Instances and there Status.

```
import boto.rds

#Connection url : Required region, access_key, secret_access_key
conn = boto.rds.connect_to_region('ap-south-1', aws_access_key_id='<aws access key>', aws_secret_access_key='<aws secret key>')

#dbinstances will have all database instances name
dbinstances = conn.get_all_dbinstances()

#We can iterate and print one by one db instance name and status.
for rds_db in dbinstances:
    print(rds_db,' = ', rds_db.status)
```